# cordova platform add android got following errors

Tags: android, ionic3

**my package.json 
**

---

```
{
  "name": "ionic-app-base",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/action-sheet": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^3.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-update": "^3.9.2",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/camera-preview": "^3.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^3.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "action-sheet": "^1.0.5",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ion2-calendar": "^1.0.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-image-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionic2-city-picker": "^0.0.4",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jsqr": "^0.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "pouchdb": "^6.1.2",
    "pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite": "^2.0.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.3"    
  }
}
```

### ionic info

```
D:\03-bak\baiduoke>ionic info
```

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : not installed
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms               : none
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.2.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.0
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.0.3
```

### **my errors i've got following errors when run command**

```
    D:\03-bak\baiduoke>cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2
                Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-13T08_58_46_055Z-debug.log`
```

I've got above errors  when i run cordova platform add android  or cordova plugin ls

Comment: after I install these package , i got D:\03-bak\baiduoke>cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2
                Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-13T08_58_46_055Z-debug.log

Comment: try `ionic cordova platform add android` and `ionic cordova plugin ls`

Answer (score 1):

> Cordova CLI      : not installed

You will need to install cordova as well for this to work. Ionic cli uses cordova cli as well.

Check [installation docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/).

Do:

```
npm install cordova -g
```

Then try your command.

Comment: glad it worked.. consider marking the answer as correct to help anyone else with the issue :)